# Upgrade cassandra 2.1.19 cluster to 3.11.1

Tags: cassandra

I want to upgrade cassandra 2.1.19 cluster to 3.11.1 without downtime.
Will 3.11.1 nodes work together with 2.1.19 nodes at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Key point will be how you connect to your cluster. You will need to try out on test systems if everything works from your application side doing the switch.

I recommend a two stop process in this case, migrate from 2.1.19 to 3.0.x - one node at atime.

For every node do the following (i said you need to test before before going to production right?):

- nodetool drain - wait for finish
- stop cassandra
- backup your configs, the old one wont work out of the box
- remove the cassandra package / tarball
- read about the java and other cassandra 3.x requirements and ensure you met them
- add the repo and install the 3.0.x package or tar ball
- some packages start the node immediately - you may have to stop them again
- make up the new config files (diff or something will be your friend, read the docs about the new options), one time only you should be able to resuse if on all the other nodes
- start cassandra (did I say test this on a test system?) and wait until the node has joined the ring again `nodetool status`
- upgrade your sstables with `nodetool upgradesstables` - almost always needed, dont skip this even if "something" works right now
- this upgrade tends to be really slow - it's just a single thread running rewriting all your data, so i/o will be a factor here
- all up and running -> go ahead to the next node and repeat

After that - upgrade 3.0.x to 3.11.x in the same fashion, add the new repo, configure for 3.11.x as for 3.0.x above and so on. But this time you can skip upgrading sstables as the format stays the same (but it wont harm if you do so).

Did I mention to do this on testing system first? One thing that will happen and may break things - older native protocols will be gone as well as rpc/ thrift.

Hope I didn't miss something ;)

Comment: Is migration to 3.0.x is a redundant intermediate step? Can I migrate directly to 3.11.1?

Comment: if you have a test environment you can try to skip this step - but I would not recommend it, there were major changes in the storage engine. This is why upgrade sstables is needed when migrating vom 2.1.x to 3.0.x. Give it a try and share the result.

Comment: I got a reply from two sources: one guy is DataStax employee, another one is from DataStax academy Slack channel, both told me to skip the intermediate step: "yes, just don't try to bootstrap, repair, or decommission during the upgrade process" and in Slack channel I got a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094935/apache-cassandra-upgrade-3-x-from-2-1

Comment: We upgraded from 2.1.21 to 3.11.6 and found a rf=1 table lost lot of partitions.